# model_dir attribute not sending the model to the S3 bucket using Python Sagemaker SDK

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

Using the Python Sagemaker SDK, one can launch a training job using TensorFlow with the following code specifying the S3 bucket where the results should be placed on the attribute `model_dir`:

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

sess = sagemaker.Session()
tf_estimator = TensorFlow(model_dir='s3://bucket_name', ...)
tf_estimator.fit(...)
```

However, after training is done, I can see the output on the default Sagemaker bucket but not on the specified bucket, what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer thanks to AWS support:

The `TensorFlow` estimator has as a base class `sagemaker.estimator.Framework` which in turn has as a base class `sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase` which accepts the parameter `output_path`.

So the initialization of the `TensorFlow` estimator to pass a custom output bucket  would look like:

```
S3_BUCKET = 's3://xxx'
tf_estimator = TensorFlow(..., output_path=S3_BUCKET)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for.. tried in vain by tweaking model_dir, default_bucket etc.,